# WD 3Tb internal hard disk detecting as 700gb

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

My new i7 computer cannot detect a newly installed 3TB hard disk as 3TB but rather reads it as 700GB. My motherboard model is Intel DH67BL. I have windows 7 64 bit. I have enabled UEFI in the BIOS. I have initialized it as GPT. What am I doing wrong here. I was told that my motherboard supports 3TB hard disks

Comment: You will need to be more specific.  Exactly where do you see 700GB?

Comment: after i initialize the disk without formatting the drive, it shows unallocated 700 gb. Also i tried formatting it and its creates a single partition of 700 gb

Comment: Be careful which SATA port you are using. If it is on the eSATA compatible port, switch to another one. Also, update/install the Intel chipset drivers.

Comment: @Bora i have put the hard disk on sata 6gbps slot

Comment: What about the Intel Chipset Drivers? Also, please provide a screenshot of your Disk Manager (see @psusi s comment)

Comment: @Bora It shows that the chipset driver are upto date, I checked it on the website, will attach a screenshot soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either your disk driver or disk controller can not handle > 32 bit addressing.  Since this is Windows 7, its AHCI driver should be able to handle this.  Go into your bios and make sure the controller is in ACHI mode, not IDE mode.  It should work either way, but my guess is that it's in IDE mode and the Windows IDE driver has a bug that prevents it from addressing > 32 bits.

Comment: its in achi mode

Comment: @Megan, which disk driver are you using?

Comment: what disk driver? please enlighten me . . i have no clue about this . . and btw my hdd didnt come with a HBA card

Comment: @Megan, open the device manager, view devices by connection, and drill down until you find the disk drive.  Then look up one level at the controller it is connected to, open the properties on it, and look at the driver tab.

Answer (score 0):

Check the disk format. NTFS, Fat32, etc..

The best solution is format your disk to NTFS and split the disk to 2 partitions.

In this article you can read the file systems limitations: [NTFS compared to FAT and FAT32](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779002.aspx)

> NTFS has always been a more powerful file system than FAT and FAT32. Windows 2000, Windows XP, and the Windows Server 2003 family include a new version of NTFS, with support for a variety of features including Active Directory, which is needed for domains, user accounts, and other important security features. For more details about features in NTFS, see NTFS.
>
> FAT and FAT32 are similar to each other, except that FAT32 is designed for larger disks than FAT. The file system that works most easily with large disks is NTFS.